# Why don't my edited videos play from certain urls?

Tags: html, css, video

I made a webpage with a video that runs as a fullscreen background-image, at:
http://79.170.44.219/grotto.com/JupiterBrewing/landingPage.html

If I use the html with the url code in this block:

```
<div class="screen" id="screen-1" data-video="http://ia600803.us.archive.org/4/items/BirdsAndFeederroyaltyFreeStockVideo/BirdsAndFeeder.mp4">
```

it works.
If I use the url below for my edited video, which I uploaded, it does not run: https://vimeo.com/129360280, I also uploaded my edited video to youtube and tried to use it as my url.

Comment: FYI that html you provided cannot show a video without attentional javascript. That linked page asks me to activate flash, no way use html5 with the video tag. Let flash die!

Comment: Why would different urls make a difference, the only one that works is the iaa600803...I have shown. I've tried dropbox, vimeo, google drive. I would like a "cloud" storage to put some small, edited mp4s that fit with my website. The mp4s work when I use them locally in VS/IIS, and have them in a local file, but my web server company will only run the one with the url. Maybe I can find a web server provider that would allow storing the mp4s at their server, not a separate url. Thanks.

Comment: I know there was an issue with IIS and mp4 files. I guess you need to add the mimetype for mp4 files. The IIS does not transmit files with unknown mimetypes AFIK.

Comment: My local host, IIS, plays mp4s just fine, it's my webserver that seems to play only from one url address that I've used and I'd like to be able to use a "cloud" file storage to hold my "custom" edited short mp4s, unless there is a solution to providing a dependable http source. Thanks. I'll look up how to add mimetypes.